# SwiftUI DatePicker Custom Font

Tags: swiftui, datepicker, uikit

Is there any straight way, that is not `DatePickerStyle`, to change the font and weight of a `DatePicker`

```swift
DatePicker("Start date",
           selection: Binding(get:{goal.startDate!},set:{goal.startDate = $0}),
           displayedComponents: .date
)
.font(.custom("HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 10, relativeTo: .caption))//<-- do nothing
.labelsHidden()
```